# Facebook Graph API Explorer behind HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-graph-api

I keep getting the following error when I try to test one of my pages with Graph API Explorer:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3502) Object at URL https://example.com/place/123456-Something has og:type of 'website'. The property 'bar' requires an object of og:type 'example:bar'.  (http response code: 401)", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3502
  }
}
```

The problem is that this page is behind HTTP Basic Authentication and it returns *401 Unauthorized* even if I pass proper credentials to authenticate for this page. I can't believe it but this seems to me that **Graph API Explorer** does not support HTTP Basic Authentication. Does anyone had this issue before and know how to force Graph API Explorer to be able to authenticate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the scraper (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) cannot reach your page then it's not possible.

Open Graph pages must be public and reachable.

> Using self-hosted objects requires that you host them as pages on your own webserver and all self-hosted objects are public.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/

Comment: @MichałCzapko https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/ `Using self-hosted objects requires that you host them as pages on your own webserver and all self-hosted objects are public.`

Comment: Ok, but I think Facebook should consider allow playing with pages behind *HTTP Basic Auth* at least for development.

Comment: @MichałCzapko This will be something you have to take up with Facebook maybe in a developer bug report.

Answer (score 0):

You can either punch a hole in basic auth via user agent (not secure, since that is trival to spoof) or Facebook's [published list of crawler IP addresses](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler).

I've written a quick PHP script [here](https://gist.github.com/xenotropic/9d4570cfa956553166c8665ba34a8e08) to generate an htaccess that includes simple auth and those IPs. FB says they shift the crawler IPs, so you'd want to do cron that script to regenerate the htaccess every so often.